# Getting an error, when trying to insert keys in environment variables and use them for GetStream.io feed

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, babeljs, getstream-io

I use GetStream.io for my app, exactly for a news feed. When I just try to insert my api key and token straight to a StreamApp component, then I receive an error that I can't use them publicly, because there is a risk that somebody can steal it. So what I discovered is to use babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables package. 
So this is how my code looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StreamApp, FlatFeed, } from 'react-native-activity-feed';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
var stream = require('getstream');

export default class newsFeed extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   appid: process.env['REACT_APP_API_ID'],
   apptoken: process.env['REACT_APP_TOKEN'],
   apikey: process.env['REACT_APP_API_KEY']
 };
}

render() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}>
     <StreamApp
        apiKey={this.state.apikey}
        appId={this.state.appid}
        token={this.state.apptoken}
     />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
 }
}
```

How you can understand, prcoess.env variables are saved in .env file. The file is connected to .babelrc file.

The issue is that I receive an error: 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'.

What is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Stream client-side (browser) you need to communicate with Stream APIs using a user token instead of api key and secret.

User tokens must be created on a trusted environment (eg. your server / cloud function) using your app's credentials and passed to your client.

```
var stream = require('getstream');

client = stream.connect(apiKey, apiSecret, appId);
const userToken = client.createUserToken('the-user-id');
```

Comment: but what should I use as parameters for <StreamApp> then?

Comment: apiKey and userToken; you can find the same on the tutorial https://getstream.io/react-activity-feed/tutorial/

Comment: for me would be more useful if you could send me a link with a tutorial on how to connect client-side with my server please